# no EOL after append to file in python

Tags: python, file-io, append, eol

I try to append to file with python using this code:

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("appended text")
```

The problem is that when I open a file with vim, I get a message from vim at the bottom:

```
"test.txt" [noeol] 2L, 27C
```

As I understand that means there is no EOL in that file. And it happens after appending with python. If I print the file with `cat`, I get:

```
user@myubuntu:~/py_code$ cat test.txt
appended text
appended textuser@myubuntu:~/py_code$
```

When I edit test.txt with vim and save, afterwards I get results from cat:

```
user@myubuntu:~/py_code$ cat test.txt
appended text
appended text
user@myubuntu:~/py_code$
```

Pay attention that "user@myubuntu:~/py_code$" now is on the new line as it should be. So I make conclusion there is some problem with EOL after appending with python, but I do not understand why and how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append newline (`\n`) to each line.

```
myfile.write("appended text\n")
```

PS. EOL (end-of-line) is newline.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which is terribly simple. I was playing with '\n' but didn't get expected results.
And now your suggestion works!